# Can I add custom authenticate rest api in keycloak?

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I find keycloak restful authentication api in postman，like this:

[image]

I know this api will return keycloak token if I give correct username and password. But now, I want to custom a api to let keycloak to finish authenticate like this, then I can obtain a keycloak token.

I read keycloak doc, but I think authentication spi can't achieve.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by letting keycloak to finish authenticate like this? Do you want to send user/pass to keycloak and fetch a token so that you could use that token to call an API that requires authentication? Do you get any error when trying to call this endpoint on postman and want to know why it doesn't work?

Comment: thanks for your reply! I just want to implement a api that I send a code to keycloak and keycloak will return keycloak token. So I can use this token to call my springboot   api which integrate with keycloak adapter. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new API (rest endpoint) to Keycloak is possible, but you should not (and probably can not) use it to add such a custom authentication. Keycloak as an identity provider is OAuth/OIDC Connect compliant and the endpoints to get/exchange a token are all part of those specifications. So if you want to protect your API using a token provided by Keycloak, you should follow the steps specified on those specs. I suggest you to read a couple of OAuth/OpenID Connect tutorials on the Internet or have a look at a post like [this](https://frontegg.com/blog/oauth-flows#:%7E:text=OAuth%20flows%20are%20essentially%20processes,involvement%20for%20back%2Dend%20systems.). You should first decided what OAuth flow matches your use-case. Then you can go to the Keycloak console and configure clients for your applications. I guess probably you would need one for the caller and one for the service that is going to be called so that they could authenticate themselves to Keycloak. I don't think that for your scenario, you would need any customization on Keycloak.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I know the authentication flow in OAuth and OIDC protocol. But in my situation, front end can obtain oidc authorization code directly from social authenticator (like google) in Authorization Code Flow, then it need to give the authorization code to back end to obtain token from social authenticator. I know keycloak have google social authenticator, just use google for example, it isn't google actually. So I want to implement a api in keycloak to finish obtain token from social authenticator. I don't understand what's mean that you said one client for caller.

Comment: I think public client or credential client in keycloak maybe can't achive it. Can you tell me more info ?